# Use existing CMS output as data for Single File Components (Vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have access to the templates that CMS uses to generate pages. This CMS is very primitive. The output is pieces of HTML.

I want to use this data in Single File Components. Most importantly, this data should not be rendered by the browser. I figured that wrapping the CMS output into a `noscript` tag would work. Then I just parse the string from the `noscript` to get HTML.

This method is pretty dirty and it does not use the power of Vue.js templates. I'm wondering if there is a better way?

CMS template:

```html
<noscript id="cms-output">
  <!-- HTML generated by CMS -->
</noscript>
```

Main JavaScript file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './app.vue'

const cmsOutput = document.getElementById('cms-output')
const parser = new DOMParser()
Vue.prototype.$cms = parser.parseFromString(cmsOutput.innerHTML, 'text/html')

Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({ render: (h) => h(App) }).$mount('#app')
```

Single File Component:

```html
<template>
  <div v-html="content"></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    content: function() {
      const contentElement = this.$cms.querySelector('.content')
      // contentElement manipulations here (working with descendants, CSS classes, etc)
      return contentElement.outerHTML
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DOM-injected HTML (or even JavaScript strings) as a template in your SFC but you'll need to enable Vue's [runtime compiler](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler).  Add the following to the project's `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Wrap the content of your HTML output in an `x-template`:

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="cms-output">
  ...
</script>
```

In your SFC, don't use `<template></template>` tags.  Instead, use the `template` option in your component (this is what the runtime compiler is needed for):

```html
<script>
  export default {
    template: '#cms-output'
  }
</script>
```

Now you can use the template just as if it were defined in the SFC, with directives, mustache syntax, etc.

## EDIT (based on feedback)

There's nothing unique or complex about this if I understand correctly.  Use a normal component / template.  Since the output isn't ready to be used as a template then there is no choice but to parse it.  You could load it from AJAX instead of embedding it as in your question but either way works.  Your component could look something like this:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data1: '',
      data2: '',
      dataN: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    const contentElement = this.$cms.querySelector('.content');
    const arrayOfData = parseTheContent(contentElement);
    this.data1 = arrayOfData[1];
    this.data2 = arrayOfData[2];
    ...
    this.dataN = arrayOfData[100];
  }
}
```

And you'd use a standard template:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    Some stuff {{ data1 }}.  Some more stuff {{ data2 }}.<br />
    {{ dataN }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, thanks! The problem is that I don't have access to the structure of HTML that the CMS outputs, so I cannot write the `x-template` properly. I think that I still need to hide the CMS output, and then pull out the necessary data for the components. I don't see any other way 

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm confused about what you want to happen.  What do you mean by "pull out the necessary data"?

Comment: I mean, I’m thinking about using the output of the CMS to build some kind of structure from which the SFCs will then request data. Maybe I should create some JS object and fill it with the escaped CMS output (`<script>window.cmsOutput = { ... }</script>`) 

Comment: I added some more thoughts in my answer.